# Keras regression does not pass through the origin

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, non-linear-regression

I am a beginner in machine learning and I want to predict a nonlinear regression with Keras in Python, but Keras cannot pass through the origin even if I have some train data (0,0).
[Fail to predict (0,0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPk24.png)

But if I add a lot more train data (0,0), Keras finally manage to pass through.
[Prediction passing through the origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwVhu.png)

However, I don't want to add those data manually in order to predict correctly the output.

Is there a way to force Keras to pass through the origin?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide a concrete architecture/model structure, so that advices specific to your model can be given. But here are two general rules to follow that will work in most scenarios.

1. Pass `use_bias=False` to **every** keras layers
2. only use activations that satisfy `f(0)=0`, e.g. `relu` ,`linear`, etc...